# On refresh getting 404 error after enabling $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm developing an application on angularjs. I tried to remove "index.html#/" from url and used

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in my route.js  file (full code snippet provided below). Now my main problem to remove "#" from url is resolved but a new bug arise i.e. now when I'm on a view i.e. `localhost:2124/Bill-Payment`and press `CTRL + F5` my application redirects me to 404 / default route which I set in route.js file. Now what I want is "when I refresh my view I land on same view/page not on default".

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])
.config(function ($locationProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider) {

   // MAIN ROUTE
    $stateProvider


    // START PAGE ROUTE END


    // LOGIN PAGE ROUTE START
        .state('login', {
            url: '/Bill-Payment',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })


    // NEW MAIN ROUTE END
    $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll();
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    // OTHERWISE ROUTE
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Index");


});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are these all your routes? There's no `/Bill-Payment` route here. which means it will go to `/Index` as specified by your `.otherwise` route

Comment: Bro, /Bill-Payment is just an example btw I edited code.